# How to show classnames of one div or more than one in textContent

Tags: javascript, html

How to show classnames of one div or more than one in textContent
I just tried this but there is something missing

```
var myDiv = document.querySelector("div"),
result = document.querySelector("div");
result.innerHTML += myDiv.classList;



    <div id="show hide line">Hello everybody</div>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: There's nothing in your code that has any relationship to classes.

Answer (score 1):

The first `div` should have `class=` not `id=`.

And if you want to target the `div` with the `id` of `result` than you should use `.getElementById()` because `.querySelector()` returns the first matching element, which (with your `div` selector) is the first `div`, not the second.

Lastly, don't use `.innerHTML` when the string you are working with doesn't have any HTML. `.innerHTML` has security and performance implications. Use `.textContent` instead (and you only need `=` here, not `+=`).

```js
document.getElementById("result").textContent = 
   document.querySelector("div").classList;
```

```html
<div class="show hide line">Hello everybody</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,to be said your answer is very helpful